# Is it possible to call a function inside another script? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I open my program I want it to detect if the program is running already (if I launch it again while it's running). If it is  I want to access the already running program and call a function there. But the problem is that I don't know how to access the already running program.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you want to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). If so, I'll advise you to search some information about that. To answer the question in more detail you'll have to provide a lot more information.

Comment: Note that you are likely looking for "inter process communication (IPC)". How to best do that depends on your use-case.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I tried using socket, but couldn't any option with it. I do have the port. can I do that with the port?

Comment: @wovano it looks like multiprocessing is something like threads. How did you mean to do that? you said you need more detail, what details do you need?

Comment: @Itamar Why do you have a port without knowing how to use sockets? Is this some web server application?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I know how to use sockets, but only the basics. This is not a web server application.

Comment: Well, the simple answer to your question is "Yes". But your *actual* question basically is "How do I let two processes communicate with each other without knowing anything about multiprocessing" and I think that question is too broad for Stack Overflow. So you should learn something about it, try something and then if you're stuck and have a specific question you can ask it here. And then add details like what you want to achieve, what steps you took, the problem you encounter, etc. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the Help pages.

Comment: @wovano ok, I searched a bit about multiprocessing, but it seems like I need to use the command "put" to add a class to the queue. the problem is that I have no access to the second instance of the class so I cant put it in there.

Answer (score -1):

I am confused by what you mean by "the script is the same script", but you can use import to get a function from a different file

otherprogram.py

```
def func(a):
    return a
```

main.py

```
from otherprogram import func
print(func(5))
```

Comment: I edited the question so it's more clear now. I am not using another script, but another instance of the script...